# How do I pass a JS variable to the DataLayer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to pass a javascript variable to the data layer.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
            var dataTag = $('#data-tag-link').attr('data-tag');
            dataTag = "'" + dataTag + "'";
            console.log(dataTag);

            dataLayer = [];
            dataLayer.push({
                'data-tag': dataTag,
                'data-author': '$Author.xml'
            });
        });
```

The dataLayer is sending the name of the variable however rather than the actual value of the variable, for example it is sending 'dataTag' rather than 'Mobile' which it should be. Any ideas on what this issue could be?

Comment: Could you post your MarkUp code?

Comment: Why do you add the quotes to dataTag ? I'm not sure if they are harmful but they are certainly not necessary (literal strings need to be quoted before adding them to the dataLayer, but not variables).

Comment: I ended up passing this with PHP like author.xml. $Tag.XML would not pass for some reason which is still unknown as it was successfully called in the HTML. However I passed this as a PHP variable set in the CMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to quote `dataTag` the way you did. This should be enough:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     var dataTag = $('#data-tag-link').attr('data-tag');

     dataLayer = [];
     dataLayer.push({
            'dataTag': dataTag,
            'dataAuthor': '$Author.xml'
     });
});
```

I'd also recommend to use camelCase for the object properties. That way you will be able later in TagManager to use them as identifiers in a Makro: `dataLayer.dataTag`